# How to play a video (wmv file) in wp7 silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, video

i want to play video in my app. I see around but nothing helped me. I ask the user if he wants to listen to his phone music. If clicks ok the music continue playing, if not then the music stop. That is ok from now. Now, my problem is: I create a grid to use it like popup with width and height and so on.. When this popup appears the music stops. This is why can not certify my app in marketplace.
Here is a little code: i believe is easy to understand... Please help!

```
public void new_grid(int v)
        {
            Grid gr = new Grid();
            gr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
            gr.Opacity = 1.0;
            gr.Width = 400;
            gr.Height = 600;
            // Create a white border.
            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(7.0);

            MediaElement video_ship = new MediaElement();
            //video_ship.AutoPlay = false;

            video_ship.Width = 400;
            video_ship.Height = 600;
            video_ship.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            video_ship.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            if (v == 1)
            {
                video_ship.Source = new Uri("videos/Lost_Ship.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                //video_ship.Play();
                gr.Children.Add(video_ship);
            }
            else if (v == 2)
            {
                //video_ship.Source = "videos/Lost_Ship.wmv";
                video_ship.Source = new Uri("videos/you_are_on_fire.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                //video_ship.Name = "fire";
                //video_ship.Play();
                gr.Children.Add(video_ship);
            }
            else if (v == 3)
            {
                //video_ship.SourceName = "videos/Lost_Ship.wmv";
                video_ship.Source = new Uri("videos/EscapeShip.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                //video_ship.Name = "escape";
                //video_ship.Play();
                gr.Children.Add(video_ship);
            }
```

I send a variable v to select one of my videos..I set the videos to Build Action Content

Any ideas what to do? or something different than this?
I want only to play the video ..Video does not have music ..or sound effect..

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works. You want to popup video when you call event. so you shoud put grid inside file xaml code and it is hidden.
This is my test

on xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">  
        <Image Source="BackgroundMain3.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <Grid Height="400" Width="600" x:Name="playvideo" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <MediaElement x:Name="element"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,684,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

on xaml.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            poupup(3);
            playvideo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            playvideo.Opacity = 0.8;
            element.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(element_MediaOpened);
        }

        void element_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            element.Play();
        }

        public void poupup(int v)
        {
            if (v == 1)
            {
                element.Source = new Uri("videos/Lost_Ship.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            else if (v == 2)
            {

                element.Source = new Uri("videos/you_are_on_fire.wmv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            }
            else if (v == 3)
            {
                element.Source = new Uri("YouTube.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            }

        }
```

Comment: I did not test your suggestion, but i think it would not be very good to navigate all the time through xaml pages... But i think this: When playing music i will not show the popup with videos, otherwise i will..Do you think this is better solution? Could it be work?